# Adding JButtons with a loop and changing them when pressed

Tags: java, xml, user-interface, parsing, jbutton

I'm trying to build a program that parses an XML file and produces a GUI using attributes from the XML it uses a loop to make JButtons and add them to the GUI so that it can have as many buttons as required when a button is pressed the GUI should refresh displaying new buttons. This is what I've got so far:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.jdom.*;
import org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder;

public class TextAdventureGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    /**
     * @wbp.nonvisual location=-20,79
     */
    private final JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                    File inputFile = new File("input");
                    SAXBuilder saxB = new SAXBuilder();

                    Document doc = saxB.build(inputFile);

                    Element storyElement = doc.getRootElement();

                    List<Element> scenesList = storyElement.getChildren();

                    Element sceneElement = scenesList.get(1);
                    List<Element> choicesList = sceneElement.getChildren();

                    TextAdventureGUI frame = new TextAdventureGUI(sceneElement, choicesList);
                    frame.setVisible(true);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public TextAdventureGUI(Element scene, List<Element> choices) {


        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 482, 311);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 0));

        //String buttonNames[] = {"choice1", "choice2", "choice3", "choice4", "choice5"};
        JButton[] cButtons = new JButton[18];

        for(int temp = 1; temp <= choices.size(); temp++)
        {
            Element choice = choices.get(temp);
            //String bName = buttonNames[temp];
            cButtons[temp] = new JButton(choice.getChildText("choiceDescription"));
            cButtons[temp].addActionListener(this);
            contentPane.add(cButtons[temp]);

        }

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(scene.getChildText("sceneDescription"));
        textArea.setBounds(5, 11, 451, 104);
        contentPane.add(textArea);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

and here's the XML I'm parsing:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<Story>
    <Scene id = "scene1">
        <SceneDescription>Insert Scene Description
        </SceneDescription>

        <choice no="1">
            <choiceDescription>choice description 1 </choiceDescription>
            <outcome>end1</outcome>
        </choice>

        <choice no="2">
            <choiceDescription>choice description 2 </choiceDescription>
            <outcome>scene3</outcome>
        </choice>
    </Scene>

    <Scene id = "scene2">
        <SceneDescription>This is the scene to parse
        </SceneDescription>

        <choice no="1">
            <choiceDescription>choice description 1 </choiceDescription>
            <outcome>scene1</outcome>
        </choice>

        <choice no="2">
            <choiceDescription>choice description 2 </choiceDescription>
            <outcome>scene3</outcome>
        </choice>
    </Scene>

    <Scene id = "scene3">
        <SceneDescription>Insert Scene Description
        </SceneDescription>

        <choice no="1">
            <choiceDescription>choice description 1 </choiceDescription>
            <outcome>end1</outcome>
        </choice>

        <choice no="2">
            <choiceDescription>choice description 2 </choiceDescription>
            <outcome>scene1</outcome>
        </choice>
    </Scene>

    <Scene id = "end1">
        <SceneDescription>ending
        </SceneDescription>

    </Scene>

</Story>
```

I don't know where to go from here I don't want to have another loop making the new buttons inside the first loop but I cant think of a way to build the second loop on it's own and still keep my variables in scope or Ideally re-purpose the same loop to display the new buttons, if someone with a better understanding of GUI building than me could give me some advice on how to make this work it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed it to use a JList instead of JButtons that fixed the issue